# How to use if else for an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I want to use an `if` condition on my array.
Here is my code:

```
String[] result = value_got.split(" ");    
String fabric = result[5];
```

I want to check first to see if `result[5]` has a value or not.
Because when it has a value, the app works correctly, but when it has no value, my app keeps stopping.

Comment: if ((result != null) && (result[5] != null) { fabric = result[5] } else { ... }

Answer (score 0):

You may first check the length of the array resulting from the split:

```
String[] result = valueGot.split(" ");
String fabric = result.length >= 6 ? result[5] : "";
```

Note that Java naming conventions generally frowns upon putting underscores in variable names.  Instead of using `value_got`, use `valueGot`, in camel case.